# Bool function `again()` getting same result

Tags: c++, return-value, program-entry-point, boolean-logic

I wrote a bool function `again()` to prompt the user to re-run the program, but for whatever answer the user enters the program will re-run no matter what.

```
bool again()
{
  //Local variable                                                                                                                        
  char answer;

  cout<<"Would you like to re-run? (Y/N) ";
  cin>>answer;
  cin.ignore(100,'\n');


  if(answer == 'Y' || 'y')
  {
    return true;
  }

  if(answer == 'N'  || 'n')
  {
     return false;
  }
}

...

  do
       {
         menu(gameamount,response);

         if (response == 1)
         {
           inputs(gameamount, game_count);
           writeout(gameamount);
         }
         if (response == 2)
         {
           outputs(gameamount, game_count);
         }
       }while(again());

       return 0;
}
```

I tried using else and else if and returning false after the first if-statement but that still did not work, I can't put the block of code in main to conserve space so I have to create a boolean function to ask the user to re-run the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a logic error in your code.

Try this:

```
if(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
{
    return true;
}

if(answer == 'N'  || answer == 'n')
{
    return false;
}
```

You should also possibly output a message in case the user decides to type something other than `'Y'`,`'y'`,`'N'` or `'n'`.

Also, I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think that your code is always returning `true` in the first if statement because you are checking to see if `'y'` is true, which I think it always is.

```
if(answer == 'Y' || 'y')
{
    return true;
}
```

Any value other than 0 would equate to true, and the character `'y'` when treated as an integer is equal to it's corresponding ASCII code (121 in this case).

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe how I didn't pay attention to that!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line

```
if(answer == 'Y' || 'y')
```

by

```
if(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
```

Comment: He would also need to do the same for the character 'N' and 'n'

Comment: Right, but the problem is that the first condition is always true, so the second one is never evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (answer == 'Y' || 'y')
```

will enter the `if` block *in every case*, since it won't evaluate to what you intended. It evaluates `answer == 'Y'` which is true or false, but then ORs this value with `'y'`. In this step, `'y'` is converted to a boolean value in order to be ORed logically, and since all numbers unequal to 0 are converted to `true` the whole expression is always `true`.

If you correct this to

```
if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
```

you still have the following problem:

Your function only returns a value in the case where the user enters *either* a `Y` *or* an `N` in lower or upper case. But what if the user enters an **invalid letter**? You need to define a behavior for this situation. Currently your program doesn't have a return statement for this case, resulting in *undefined behavior*, which means the result of the function can be *anything*.

You can either return a default value (e.g. `false`), then you need to remove the second conditional `if` but keep the `return false`.

Another solution is to loop until the user entered a valid value.